# How to make a anchor with a select > option element using class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I make a anchor scrolling when you change a option in a select element. But, this works only insert a id inside of a value atribute. Can make that using href?  I'll use the value atribute for other thing. Thanks and merry christmas!!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FelipeMartinin/E3MBb/1/)

```
<!-- THIS WORK -->

<select>
   <option value="#b1">1 test</option>
   <option value="#b2">2 test</option>
   <option value="#b3">3 test</option>
 </select>

 <!-- THIS DON`T WORK =/ -->

 <select>
     <option href="#b1">1 test</option>
     <option href="#b2">2 test</option>
     <option href="#b3">3 test</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: you can't start a class with a # class="#b1"... is that just a typo in your code here? is it really class="b1" ?

Comment: You are right! I cheated here. What I want is to anchor with the "href" instead of "value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For class can do it like this:

```
  $('select').on('change', function () {
      var $el = $($(this).find(':selected').attr('class'));
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $el.offset().top
      }, 500);

  })
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E3MBb/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I cheated here. What I want is to anchor with the "href" instead of "value"

Answer (score 1):

in your fiddle you have

```
 // fluid scroll in the select>option change

      $('select').on('change', function () {


           $('html,body').animate({
                      scrollTop: $(this.value).offset().top
                  }, 500);
      });
  });
```

here for scrollTop you have given `$(this.value)`, so it works only when you give `value = "#b1"`

change it to `$(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id)` and it will work for `id="#b1"`

Comment: `this` is the `select`, still have to get id from `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/E3MBb/5/

Works with class, even though I find it strange to use class in that way. The correct way would be to use value in my mind, but here you go :)

Its easy to edit the fiddle to get the selected options id, href or what ever other attribute you want other than value, that's best gotten with `this.value` like before.

Comment: @gaurav5430 `($this.id)` will get the `id` of `select`, not the selected option.

Comment: @guarav5430 and there you got the up-vote for compact good example :)